# PyInstaller Security-Alert: try to store file outside of dist-directory

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

i'm trying to compile a python program to an *.exe file using PyInstaller ([link to docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html)). I have used [pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu/) to build the application. I'm using the `pyinstall application.spec` option. My application is build from different modules:

```
Tool:
|_ ApplicationFolder
|    - __init__.py
|    - application.py
|    - application.ui
|    - application.spec
|_ ModuleFolder1
|_ ModuleFolder2
```

I'm running the `pyinstall` command in the folder `\Tool\ApplicationFolder\`

In my `application.spec` file I put:

```
data_files = [("application.ui", "."]
```

as shown in the documentation from `pygubu` ([link](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu/tree/master/examples/pyinstaller)). This resulst in an error stating the file `application.ui` is not in the directory. So I tried to specify the full path to the location of the .ui file, like this:

```
data_files = [("application.ui", r"C:\path\to\file")]
```

This raises the error `Security-Alert: try to store file outside of dist-directory. Aborting.`

Now i'm a bit lost, anyone who has experience with this 'problem'?

Answer (score 1):

Used a work around, and stored all the files in one folder. Not the way to go but it did work for now (as time was becoming scarce)